# Unable to Clear Timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function that performs a setTimeout back on itself, i.e.:

```
var doIt = function(){
 $('#comment_report').trigger('apexrefresh');
  setTimeout("doIt()", 5000);
}
```

My question is, I am trying to clear the setTimeout that is looping through every 5 seconds, by issuing:

```
clearTimeout(doIt);
```

Unfortunately this didn’t work.

How would I go about clearing the above setTimeout?

Comment: 6 answers in 4 minutes...  how you know you should have googled it... :-)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't pass a string to `clearTimeout()`, you pass the `Number` which identifies the `setTimeout()` (which is returned by said function).

```
var timeoutId = null;

var doIt = function() {
    $('#comment_report').trigger('apexrefresh');
    timeoutId = setTimeout(doIt, 5000);
};

clearTimeout(timeoutId);
```

Alternatively, inside of `doIt()`, check for the condition and if it's met, then `return` only before you issue another call to `setTimeout()` (you won't have to keep track of the id that way).

Comment: Thanks. For the record, I actually tried this but didn't seem to work for me but works fine now - obviously missed something. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
var doit = function(){

};

var my_timeout_name = setTimeout( doit, 5000 );

clearTimeout( my_timeout_name );
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` returns you an id that you can then pass to `clearTimeout` function.

Also, instead of this:

```
setTimeout("doIt()", 5000);
```

You can just pass a function:

```
setTimeout(doIt, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myTimeout = false;
var doIt = function(){
 $('#comment_report').trigger('apexrefresh');
 myTimeout = setTimeout(doIt, 5000);
}
```

Then you should use

```
clearTimeout(myTimeout);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong `clearTimeout(timerid)` this function takes the id of Timeout.
you can achieve this as

```
var mytimerid;

  var doIt = function()
  {
    $('#comment_report').trigger('apexrefresh');
    mytimerid = setTimeout("doIt()", 5000);
  }
```

and then when ever required stop the timeout by

```
 clearTimeout(mytimerid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a variable to the setTimeout that holds the `id`.

But in your code you seem to be assigning `doIt` to a function that does not return anything.

```
    var timer;

       timer = setTimeout("doIt()", 5000);
```

Then use

```
   if(timer)
      clearTimeout(timer);
```